# Android: Show a contextual menu bar when click on a textview

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextmenu

I have tried http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-a-contextual-menu-bar-contextual-action-mode-for-a-single-view-in-android/

with AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="tvt.webviewdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="tvt.webviewdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

But I has a error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tvHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_hello);

    mCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() { // error line <<<<<

        /**
         * Invoked whenever the action mode is shown. This is invoked
         * immediately after onCreateActionMode
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        /** Called when user exits action mode */
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mMode = null;
        }

        /**
         * This is called when the action mode is created. This is called by
         * startActionMode()
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Demo");
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        /** This is called when an item in the context menu is selected */
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action1:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected Action1 ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mode.finish(); // Automatically exists the action mode, when
                                // the user selects this action
                break;
            case R.id.action2:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected Action2 ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action3:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected Action3 ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    OnLongClickListener listener = new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mMode != null)
                return false;
            else
                mMode = startActionMode(mCallback);
            return true;
        }
    };

    tvHello.setOnLongClickListener(listener);

}
```

EDIT - Error Log:

```
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  tvt.webviewdemo.MainActivity$1
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at tvt.webviewdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-11 20:45:24.600: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can u post your error log??

Comment: I have just posted it

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mistake in inflating contextual layout inside `onCreateActionMode()`:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
```

It should be inflated using ActionMode object:

```
 mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
```